# use a function outside render method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code like this:

//my_file.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {//something};
    },
    myFunction:function(html){
        //some code
    },
    render:function(){
        //some code
        var someVar1, someVar2, someVar3;
        someVar1.map( function(i, j){
            someVar2.campos.map( function(k, j){
                someVar3.campos.map( function(z, k){
                    this.myFunction(something);
                }
            }
        }
        return (
            <div>
                { //something }
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports=App;
```

my_file.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: this.myFunction is not a function. What I'm doign wrong? How I use that function inside the render?

Comment: this inside a function is probably points to window object not your component object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that in `.map` `this` refers to global scope not to your component. There are several ways how you can solve this problem

1. set `this` for each `.map`

   ```
   someVar1.map( function(i, j){
     someVar2.campos.map( function(k, j){
       someVar3.campos.map( function(z, k){
         this.myFunction(something);
       }, this);
     }, this)
   }, this)
   ```
2. store `this` in variable

   ```
   var self = this;
   someVar1.map( function(i, j){
     someVar2.campos.map( function(k, j){
       someVar3.campos.map( function(z, k){
         self.myFunction(something);
       });
     })
   })
   ```
3. use arrow functions

   ```
   someVar1.map( (i, j) => {
     someVar2.campos.map( (k, j) => {
       someVar3.campos.map( (z, k) => {
         this.myFunction(something);
       });
     })
   })
   ```